# what can I use to replace sleep and usleep in my Qt app?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm importing a portion of existing code into my Qt app and noticed a sleep function in there.  I see that this type of function has no place in event programming.  What should I do instead?

UPDATE: After thought and feedback I would say the answer is: call sleep outside the GUI main thread only and if you need to wait in the GUI thread use processEvents() or an event loop, this will prevent the GUI from freezing.

Comment: What is the `sleep()` used for?

Comment: it is used as a delay between sending a UDP packet and receiving an answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this QTime solution fail at midnight?

Comment: yes it would.  A better solution would be a QWaitCondition or something of the sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to break down the events at all.  All I needed to do was to call `QApplication::processEvents()` where `sleep()` was and this prevents the GUI from freezing.

Answer (score 12):

It isn't pretty but I found this in the [Qt mailing list archives](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2005-08/thread00071-0.html):

The sleep method of QThread is protected, but you can expose it like so:

```
class SleeperThread : public QThread
{
public:
    static void msleep(unsigned long msecs)
    {
        QThread::msleep(msecs);
    }
};
```

Then just call:

```
SleeperThread::msleep(1000);
```

from any thread.

However, a more elegant solution would be to refactor your code to use a QTimer - this might require you saving the state so you know what to do when the timer goes off.

Comment: yeah I was aware of those methods and the class SleeperThread seems the better choice but I am evaluating if using sleep in the main thread is valid practice since it seems to go against event-programming practice.

Comment: It isn't good practice IMHO - you should use the Qt UDP socket class that uses signals and slots so you *know* when there is data to read and when it is safe to write, etc.

Comment: Good point.  But now I am thinking this would require me to greatly fragment my code.  For instance.  I call getUDPdata(COMMAND_BYTE) in which the packet is sent and a reply is received.  On the lines of code following that I use this data.  If I am to do as you say then I would have to rdo the whole program and things would get very complicated wouldnt you say?

Comment: I think that hard-coded sleeps - in the hope that there will be data ready to read afterwards - is a bad idea and will bite you on the backside eventually.  I'd refactor the code if possible.

Answer (score 9):

I don't recommend sleep in a event based system but if you want to ... 
You can use a waitcondition, that way you can always interrupt the *sleep* if neccesary.

```
//...
QMutex dummy;
dummy.lock();
QWaitCondition waitCondition;
waitCondition.wait(&dummy, waitTime);
//...
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason why sleep is a bad idea in event based programming is because event based programming is effectively a form on non-preemptive multitasking. By calling sleep, you prevent any other event becoming active and therefore blocking the processing of the thread.

In a request response scenario for udp packets, send the request and immediately wait for the response. Qt has good socket APIs which will ensure that the socket does not block while waiting for the event. The event will come when it comes. In your case the QSocket::readReady signal is your friend.

If you want to schedule an event for some point of time in the future, use QTimer. This will ensure that other events are not blocked.

Comment: As mentioned sleep or usleep will block the event loop rendering the GUI dead. This means that the user will not be able to cancel the operation or even cleanly exit the application. The correct way to do this is using a state-machine http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine. Welcome to the world of event driven programming.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how the QTs handle the events internally, but on most systems at the lowest level the application life goes like this: the main thread code is basically a loop (the *message loop*), in which, at each iteration, the application calls a function that gives to it a new message; usually that function is blocking, i.e. if there are no messages the function does not return and the application is stopped.

Each time the function returns, the application has a new message to process, that usually has some recipient (the window to which is sent), a meaning (the message code, e.g. the mouse pointer has been moved) and some additional data (e.g. the mouse has been moved *to coords 24, 12*).

Now, the application has to process the message; the OS or the GUI toolkit usually do this under the hood, so with some black magic the message is dispatched to its recipient and the correct event handler is executed. When the event handler returns, the internal function that called the event handler returns, so does the one that called it and so on, until the control comes back to the main loop, that now will call again the magic message-retrieving function to get another message. This cycle goes on until the application terminates.

Now, I wrote all this to make you understand why sleep is bad in an event driven GUI application: if you notice, while a message is processed *no other messages can be processed*, since the main thread is busy running your event handler, that, after all, is just a function called by the message loop. So, if you make your event handler sleep, also the message loop will sleep, which means that the application in the meantime won't receive and process any other messages, including the ones that make your window repaint, so your application will look "hang" from the user perspective.

Long story short: don't use sleep unless you have to sleep for very short times (few hundreds milliseconds at most), otherwise the GUI will become unresponsive. You have several options to replace the *sleep*s: you can use a timer (QTimer), but it may require you to do a lot of bookkeeping between a timer event and the other. A popular alternative is to start a separate worker thread: it would just handle the UDP communication, and, being separate from the main thread, it would not cause any problem sleeping when necessary. Obviously you must take care to protect the data shared between the threads with mutexes and be careful to avoid race conditions and all the other kind of problems that occur with multithreading.

Comment: got to leave work but i will be sure to read you post later on tonight ;)